# Setting A Textfield's .text Attribute Is Clearing Everything

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a Flash CS6 AS3 project that up until yesterday was displaying text correctly. I have embedded the font Trajan Pro Bold with all of it's symbols and have text fields on my stage using that font.

One text field which has been there for a while is working correctly and changing text as it should. Other text fields are only displaying certain letters. This seems like an embedding problem but I have tried deleting the Font object in the library and recreating it to no avail.

Is there any sort of caching or anything I could clear that could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was solved by going to Edit > Preferences > Publish Cache and turning off caching. This increased build time but I was able to turn it back on afterwards to fix the problem and reduce the build time back to normal